# Importing packages inside a package in jenkins-shared-libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

My `jenkins-shared-libraries` structure is this:

```
vars
  |_mainPipeline.groovy
resources
src
 |_ com
     |_company
          |_utils.groovy
          |_data.groovy
```

utils.groovy:

```
package com.company;
def getCommitHash() {
  return "somestring"
}
return this
```

data.groovy:

```
package com.company;
def utils = new com.company.utils()
def doSomeStuff() {
  def commitHash = utils.getCommitHash()
  // Do other stuff...
}
return this
```

mainPipeline.groovy:
data.groovy:

```
def utils = new com.company.utils()
pipeline {
....
  def commitHash = utils.getCommitHash()
}
```

Importing `utils` on the `mainPipeline` works great, however, when I import it on `data.groovy` I get an exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: utils for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

How do I use `utils` inside `data`?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are your `import` statements?

Comment: Top of the file, just as in the quoted code above

Comment: None of your code in the question has `import` statements. Please update the question.

Comment: In `mainPipeline` the `def utils = new com.company.utils()` is sufficient. Maybe that’s what’s missing?

Comment: Ok normally a global var requires an import to invoke anything from that library. If that works, then that is new relative to the last version of pipeline I was using. Try `import com.company.utils` in your `data.groovy`. If that does not work, then maybe a relative of `import utils` would work. Either way this may not work, as I believe I saw a question before where the conclusion was this is not possible. I may be wrong however.

Comment: And then calling the function is the same? `utils.getCommitHash()`?

Comment: You could directly `def utils = new utils()` if the import succeeds.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard I’ll give it a go

Comment: you should use java naming conventions to name your classes